# Java "this" null check in scheduled task

Tags: java, null, this

im having some issues with a complex for me thing.
I need an null check here, but as far as we all know this != null

But what happens in a scheduled task? I have a runnable class inside an object and im using the object's methods inside that runnable after about 1 minute, but if that specific object is now null after those 60 seconds I get errors, so I just need null checks those null checks... 
For example:

```
        ThreadPoolManager.getInstance().scheduleGeneral(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                L2PcInstance.this.stopFear(true);
            }
        }, 60000);
```

L2PcInstance is the basic class/object on which I want to make the null checks

the problem is:

```
null
Exception in thread "AISTPool-7" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sf.l2j.gameserver.model.actor.instance.L2PcInstance.endSpree(L2PcInstance.java:11293)
    at net.sf.l2j.gameserver.model.actor.instance.L2PcInstance.doDie(L2PcInstance.java:4230)
    at net.sf.l2j.gameserver.model.actor.status.PcStatus.reduceHp(PcStatus.java:215)
    at net.sf.l2j.gameserver.model.actor.instance.L2PcInstance.reduceCurrentHp(L2PcInstance.java:9431)
    at net.sf.l2j.gameserver.model.actor.L2Character.reduceCurrentHp(L2Character.java:5957)
    at net.sf.l2j.gameserver.model.actor.L2Character.onHitTimer(L2Character.java:4359)
    at net.sf.l2j.gameserver.model.actor.L2Character$HitTask.run(L2Character.java:2246)
    at net.sf.l2j.gameserver.ThreadPoolManager$RunnableWrapper.run(ThreadPoolManager.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

don't worry for all those classes, they are just the triggers

Comment: An object cannot be `null`. A variable can be referencing `null`.

Comment: Are you dealing with inner class?

Comment: yes, this runnable is inner to the L2PcInstance.java, the thing is, that IT IS possible for this to be null after 60 seconds, and its obvious isnt it?

Comment: To make an simple example: L2PcInstance.this is player, and that runnable is a code which runs after 60 seconds, the think is that if the player logs off, the server still runs that runnable after 60 seconds while L2PcInstance.this that triggered it is now null

Comment: I just told you, an object cannot be `null`. The variable that was referencing that object can be made to reference `null`, but that is not the same thing.

Comment: You may want to check the stack trace again to be sure where the null pointer exception is coming from. Most likely reference to the outer class (L2PcInstance.this) is not where the exception is coming from but rather somewhere in the `stopFear` method.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but you didn't understand what Im saying... Probably I explain it wrong, I can't explain it better...

Comment: Post your errors then.

Comment: stopfear is just a boolean, nothing else... Just the player logs off, and the server finalizes the object, but the runnable is running without making null checks (because its an inner class) thus it has npe or smth

Comment: We can't help you without more information. Post the code that cause the NPE and the exception stack trace.

Comment: I added the exception I found, the problem is rare but players can abuse it and hurt the game flow, there are 600 players online atm, and this happens in one out of 100 times, but Im 100% sure that the problem is there

Comment: would it be a solution to cancel the runnable upon player finalization ?

Comment: I don't see how the code you posted is related to the stack trace you posted. Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: This was an example, the L2PcInstance has lots of Runnables that are still running after object finalization, most of them are canceled uppon finalization, but those who don't really need null checks... My question was simple, is there any way to make those nullchecks? If not then the only solution is task cancel ? I don't ask for a solution here, but just for some enlightenment.

Comment: 'If that specific object is null' makes no sense. It can't be. 'I get errors': *what* errors? This is a classic XY problem. You're posting the problems you found with the solution you tried, instead of the original problem. Try posting the original problem.

Comment: If you need to do a `null` check, do a `null` check, but it won't be for `L2PcInstance.this` because that will **never** be `null`. Neither will `this`.

Comment: Your Runnable is an instance of an inner class. An inner class instance retains a reference to the outer object. The outer object therefore cannot be finalized until the Runnable has stopped running, indeed until the Runnable has become unreachable. Your question and comments therefore don't make sense. What is the *actual problem* you are experiencing?

Answer (score 2):

> but as far as we all know this != null

There's no 'as far as we all know' about it. this != null by definition.

> I have a runnable class inside an object and im using the object's methods inside that runnable after about 1 minute, but if that specific object is now null after those 60 seconds

The situation you describe is impossible. Objects don't become null. And objects which are enclosing instances of inner classes don't get finalized or garbage-collected before those inner classes.

> I get errors

No doubt, but not because the object is null. The NullPointerException in your stack trace isn't coming from the code you posted.

Comment: The object may not become null, but I CANT access it if the player logs off, however the runnable will still be runned even if the player who requested it doesnt exist anymore, so I guess the only way to stop it is to .stop(); the runnable when the PcInstance logs off.

Comment: Its complex, its not just a code, its a whole gameserver with 2kk of line code, the ThreadPoolManager class takes all of the Runnables management as you see on the code I posted, but it never gets informed that the L2PcInstance.this logged off and it can't access it anymore... So the only way to deal with this is to add a thread.stop() uppon the logoff code of the player?

Comment: I don't know what any of this means, but the code you posted does not throw the exception you posted, and L2PcInstance.this never visibly becomes null. I suggest you reformulate your question in terms of the real problem.